# GCP API Gateway is confused about JWT by adding an external load-balancer in front

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-api-gateway

I had a running setup where a backend Cloud Run service was fronted by API Gateway. The security definition was straightforward:

```
 flow: "implicit"
 type: "oauth2"
 x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
 x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
 x-google-audiences: "my-audience"
```

Now that I have added an external load-balancer (with a custom domain) by following the Google documentation ([here](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-load-balancing)), I get the following error log from API Gateway:

```
response_code_detail: "jwt_authn_access_denied{Audiences_in_Jwt_are_not_allowed}"
service_agent: "ESPv2/2.35.0"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the paths: section of your YAML contain x-google-backend: with the new custom domain?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rossco : yes I have updated my api spec with my custom domain but the bug still persists.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `x-google-backend.address` property must not be changed to the address based on the custom domain. It needs to be kept with the actual service URL of the Cloud Run backend.